# c# ExecuteNonQuery always returns Zero

Tags: c#, sql, executenonquery

I think nothing's wrong with the connection because when I open it, it does not throw any error. So I guess the error is when I'm executing a command. This is my code:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM cars", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
int numbers = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I tried using a message box to display the value of `numbers` but the result is always 0. The table cars contains 5 records. So why am I not getting the correct results?..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the anonymous downvoter, the key part of the OP:

> I tried using a message box to display the value of numbers but the
>   result is always 0. The table cars contains 5 records. So why am I not
>   getting the correct results?..

The OP is obviously trying to get a count of records in the table (a scalar aggregate) and not all of the table data.

**My answer:**

That's because your query is returning a table and not a scalar value and you're calling the incorrect function. Your query should be should be:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cars"
```

And ExecuteNonQuery doesn't actually expect any results to be returned. (You usually run insert, update and delete operations with ExecuteNonQuery.) You should be using [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar.aspx) which expects a single-valued result such as count(*).

All together now:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT count(*) FROM cars", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
int numbers = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: For a select * query like he has shown ExecuteScalar does not help.

Comment: Cool! Nice! Can't Accept yet though, it tells me "You can accept an answer after 6minutes". hehe Anyways, Thank you!

But how can I get the different fields for example id, names and such?..

Comment: @DavidePiras: If you read the question closely you'll see that the query is not correct. The OP is trying to get an aggregate... a count of records in the table.

Comment: No because question is unclear and he mentions numbers but not clearly aggregates... I didnt vote you down anyway.

Comment: @DavidePiras: No, the question is not explicit but the implication is clear. The OP expects a single number to be returned. The number of items in the table. The terms are not used but it is a scalar, aggregate value. count(*) is an aggregate function.

Comment: You cannot infer so. what if he has a column called numbers in that table? anyway does not matter. i voted you up to balance the phantom down vote of smbd else...

Answer (score 1):

Try using ExecuteScalar that should give you the count.  ExecuteNonQuery doesn't return the results from your query.  The return your looking at indicates how many rows were affected by your statement, in your case zero.

Answer (score 1):

ExecuteNonQuery as the name tells you does not make a query. it is normally used for inserts or updates and returns the number of affected records. for the query you provided you should use ExecuteReader or a DataAdapter and its Fill method to fill a datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are executing a query, and ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows effected, which when you select is always 0 since you aren't changing anything (ie. INSERT,UPDATE or DELETE)

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteNonQuery` only returns the number of rows affected for UPDATE, DELETE or INSERT operations. For the number of rows in the SELECT statement, try:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM cars", conn);
OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

int numbers = 0;
while (reader.Read())
{
    //// other Reader-related operations here...

    numbers++;
}
```

Comment: But this is really bad if he needs a count should count in SQL not client side looping of all records!

Comment: Agreed, a COUNT is much better, though am I assuming the OP may want to use the result set for other purposes.